# Generic custom regular expression with dynamic pattern used as data annotation for Model

Tags: c#, validation

I want to apply custom regular expression as data annotation for all of my Model properties.

So I create a custom regular expression with dynamic pattern like below:-

Purpose:- So the purpose of DynamicRegularExpressionAttribute  class is to make generic custom regular expressions where regx pattern could be dynamic. Source of this pattern is cache-memory data where all the properties of a model are used as keys.

```
 public class DynamicRegularExpressionAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public string PatternProperty { get;  set; }

        public Type Typeofclass { get; set; }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
    

            PropertyInfo propertyinfo = Typeofclass.GetProperty(PatternProperty);

            //PropertyInfo property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(PatternProperty);
            if (propertyinfo == null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(string.Format("{0} is unknown property", propertyinfo));
            }
            var pattern = propertyinfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null) as string;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pattern))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(string.Format("{0} must be a valid string regex",       pattern));
            }

            var str = value as string;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            {
                // We consider that an empty string is valid for this property
                // Decorate with [Required] if this is not the case
                return null;
            }

            var match = Regex.Match(str, pattern);
            if (!match.Success)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Now my Data model similar to like this:-

```
 public class WeatherForecast
    {
        [DynamicRegularExpression(PatternProperty = "TemperatureC1", Typeofclass = typeof(WeatherForecastRegularExpression))]
        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);

        [IsEmpty(ErrorMessage = "Should not be null or empty.")]
        [DynamicRegularExpression(PatternProperty = "Summary1",Typeofclass = typeof(WeatherForecastRegularExpression))]
        public string Summary { get; set; }

    }
```

So you can clearly observe that I need pass patternProperty as TemperatureC1 or Summary1 which are belongs to another class WeatherForecastRegularExpression.

Code for WeatherForecastRegularExpression.cs like this:-

```
  public static class WeatherForecastRegularExpression
    {
        public static string Summary1 => "a"; //Source from sql table

        public static string TemperatureC1 => "^-?[0-9][0-9,\\.]+$"; //source from sql table  


    }
```

Actually  patterns for regularexpression is different for each property (e.g. `Summary`, `TemperatureC`) and source of this pattern is SQL data table.

Now what I want  to avoid the step to create WeatherForecastRegularExpression.cs class or define dummy properties like `TemperatureC1` and `Summary1` beacuse I have 60 to 70 no of models in my projects. So it will be very difficult jobs for me to create dummy model for each property.Also I don't want to change model class now by adding extra property into it. Only thing I want to add data annotation for my models.

So how I can make my DynamicRegularExpressionAttribute class more generic so that I can avoid this scenario?

Any suggestion or modification would be helpful.

Comment: Have you considered `[DynamicRegularExpression("^-?[0-9][0-9,\\.]+$")] public int TemperatureC { get; set; }`?

Comment: Hello@ corvus_192,I can't pass pattern like this [DynamicRegularExpression("^-?[0-9][0-9,\\.]+$")] because this pattern will come from some sql table and it's different for temparatue and Summary. Actually during application startup we read the regx pattern table and store it in cache memory. Later we use that data to read individual pattern with respect to keys like Temparatue and Summary etc.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provides a Regular expression attribute: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute?view=net-8.0

Which, from the docs, appears to be used like this:

```
public class CustomerMetaData
{
   
    // Allow up to 40 uppercase and lowercase 
    // characters. Use custom error.
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$", 
         ErrorMessage = "Characters are not allowed.")]
    public object FirstName;

    // Allow up to 40 uppercase and lowercase 
    // characters. Use standard error.
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$")]
    public object LastName;
}
```

In your case you can just pass the attribute whatever regex you want.